# React update state of component after search through object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, sanity, use-state

I have an object that is outputted from the reactIcons npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons I am importing everything from one of the folders with `import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/fa'` I am using sanity studio, I created a text input that takes the value searched and runs a search function that runs a includes on the values from the object I grabbed from the reactIcons `fa` folder and log's the vales that match. Now I want to take those values and update a react component with `useState()` Howerver I get the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: setIcon is not defined` and SetIcon is the setter function from useState array. Here is my code so far

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import FormField from 'part:@sanity/components/formfields/default'
import PatchEvent, {set, unset} from 'part:@sanity/form-builder/patch-event'
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/fa'


console.log(ReactIcons);

const createPatchFrom = value => PatchEvent.from(value === '' ? unset() : set(String(value)))

const Example = value => {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState();

  return (
   <div>{icon}</div>
  );
}

const search = value => {
  console.log(value);
    Object.keys(ReactIcons).map(go => {
    if (go.toLowerCase().includes(value) === true){
      console.log(go);
      setIcon(go);
    }
  })
}



class IconPickerCustom extends React.Component{

    static propTypes = {
        value: PropTypes.string,
        onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    render = () =>{
        const {type, value, onChange} = this.props
        return (
          <>
            <FormField label={type.title} description={type.description}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={value === undefined ? '' : value}
                onChange={event => onChange(createPatchFrom(event.target.value))}
                ref={element => this._inputElement = element}
              />
            </FormField>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={event => search(event.target.value)}
            />
            {Object.values(ReactIcons).map(X =>{
              return (
                <>
              <X/>
              </>
              );
            })}
            {console.log(ReactIcons.Fa500Px)}
            <ReactIcons.Fa500Px/>
            <Example/>
          </>
        )
    }
}

export default IconPickerCustom;
```

Comment: Why are you using a hook when you are using a class component????   Just set and update state as normal and don't use the hook.  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: hmm, I don't know why I am. I'm not so familiar with react, I've only played with hooks before so I used them here. Could you give me a rough example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has two types of components, class components and function components (formerly stateless components).   Hooks are used in function components when you realize you need state inside a function component and prefer not to convert it to a class component.

The useState() Hook allows us to add state in a function component.

*Class Component*

```
//initialize state
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {foo: bar};
}

//set state
this.setState({foo: baz});

//read state
this.state.foo;
```

*Function Component*
(with useState() Hook)

```
//initialize state
const [icon, setIcon] = useState("myInitialValue");

//set state
setIcon("myNewValue");

//read state
{icon}
```

That being said, you already have a class component so no need to use hooks here.

```
class IconPickerCustom extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { icon: "nothing" };
}

static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const createPatchFrom = value => PatchEvent.from(value === '' ? unset() : set(String(value)));

const search = value => {
    Object.keys(ReactIcons).map(go => 
        ({ go.toLowerCase().includes(value) ? 
           this.setState({icon:go}) : null;}) 
}

render = () =>{
    const {type, value, onChange} = this.props
    return (
      <>
        <FormField label={type.title} description={type.description}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={value === undefined ? '' : value}
            onChange={event => onChange(createPatchFrom(event.target.value))}
            ref={element => this._inputElement = element}
          />
        </FormField>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={event => search(event.target.value)}
        />
        {Object.values(ReactIcons).map(X =>{
          return (
            <>
          <X/>
          </>
          );
        })}
        {console.log(ReactIcons.Fa500Px)}
        <ReactIcons.Fa500Px/>
        <Example/>
      </>
    )
}
}

export default IconPickerCustom;
```

You are going to want something along those lines.   Let me know if you have any questions.